# Insert raw file data into BLOB ("OLE Object") field of Access table using ADO

Tags: c++, ado, ole, ms-access-2013, variant

I am trying to insert a file into MS Access database, into a field of `OLE Object` type. I am using `C++` and `ADO`.

<strike>Currently I get error `Invalid pointer error`.</strike>

I think that my problem is mishandling variants since this is the first time I use them. I am learning from [this code example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but have problem understanding how to insert file from disk into `variant`.

They read it from database, and copied it into new record so the part where I read file from disk and then insert it into variant is missing.

I am firing off my code in GUI when menu item is selected. Database has one table named `test` with fields `ID` which is primary key and `field` which is of `OLE Object` type.

After searching online I have found nothing that can help me.

Here is smallest code snippet possible that illustrates the problem ( error checking is minimal):

```
wchar_t *bstrConnect = L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; \
        Data Source = C:\\Users\\Smiljkovic85\\Desktop\\OLE.accdb";

    try
    {
        HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

        // connection
        ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn(L"ADODB.Connection");

        // recordset
        ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS(L"ADODB.Recordset");

        // connect to DB
        hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, L"admin", L"", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

        // open file
        std::ifstream in(L"C:\\Users\\Smiljkovic85\\Desktop\\file.pdf",
               std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);

        // get file size
        int fileSize = in.tellg();

        // here I tried to adapt code from the example linked above
        pRS->Open(L"test", _variant_t((IDispatch*)pConn, true), 
            ADODB::adOpenKeyset, ADODB::adLockOptimistic, ADODB::adCmdTable);

        // add new record
        pRS->AddNew();

        // copy pasted
        _variant_t varChunk;

        SAFEARRAY FAR *psa;
        SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
        rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;
        // modify to our file size
        rgsabound[0].cElements = fileSize;
        psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, rgsabound);

        //=================== try to add file into variant
        char *chData = (char *)psa->pvData;

        chData = new char[fileSize];
        in.read(chData, fileSize);

        /* ============= I have even tried the following :

        char *chData = new char[fileSize];
        in.read(chData, fileSize);

        BYTE* pData;
        SafeArrayAccessData(psa, (void **)&pData);
        memcpy(pData, chData, fileSize);
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);

        ===============*/

        //=================================================

        // Assign the Safe array  to a variant. 
        varChunk.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1;
        varChunk.parray = psa;

        pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"field")->AppendChunk(varChunk);
        // add this record into DB
        pRS->Update();

        // cleanup
        delete[] chData;
        in.close();
        pRS->Close();
        pConn->Close();
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    catch (_com_error e)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, (LPWSTR)e.Description(), L"", 0);
    }
```

Can you help me to modify this code snippet so I can insert file into variant?

### EDIT:

I have searched here for help and two posts that gave me an idea. Still none of my solutions work. You can see them in the above code snippet, in the comments.

What I get now, is the following error: `a problem occurred while microsoft access was communicating with the ole server or activex control` in MS Access. I have searched online for solution but had no luck, every link claims it has to do with access and not with the code.

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using `ADODB.Connection` and `ADODB.Recordset` objects you should be able to use a binary `ADODB.Stream` object to manipulate the file contents with

- `.LoadFromFile` to fill the Stream with the file contents, and
- `.Read` to pull it back out of the Stream and store it in the database field.

Unfortunately I cannot offer a C++ example, but in VBA the code would be:

```vbs
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset, strm As ADODB.Stream
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "test", con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
Set strm = New ADODB.Stream
strm.Type = adTypeBinary
strm.Open
strm.LoadFromFile "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\test.pdf"
rst.AddNew
strm.Position = 0
rst.Fields("FileData").Value = strm.Read
rst.Update
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
strm.Close
Set strm = Nothing
```

Comment: I was able to transfer your code into C++, by using official ADO documentation and Internet examples. However, although code compiles and doesn't crash, BLOB is not inserted into database. When I open MS Access database and double click on BLOB, I get the following error: 'a problem occurred while microsoft access was communicating with the ole server or activex control'. Researching through Internet, I have learned that the problem might not be the code, but the settings in MS Access. **This might be relevant :** code is generated with Visual Studio 2013 and ran it on x64 Windows 8.1

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff The BLOB is inserted into the database as raw binary data. Try using similar C++ code to pull the document back out of the database using the `.Write` and `.SaveToFile` methods of an `ADODB.Stream` object. The reason that you cannot open the document by double-clicking on it in the Access UI is because it was not stored as an "OLE wrapped" document object. (That was the old way of storing embedded objects in Access and it has been increasingly falling out of favour in recent years.)

Comment: Already did that and it fails. I mean, I get the whole data but there is extra info added at the top and very bottom of the file. I know this because I tried to write both `pdf` and `txt`. I couldn't open the `pdf` but could `txt` and there I saw the extra lines at the very top and the bottom. The phrase that strikes me is `Package`, maybe it will help you in some way. I assume that these extra lines create the problem. Hopefully this gives you enough info to help me. Best regards.

Comment: OK, this is really weird: I have made a small program that inserts `pdf` or `txt` into database, and then immediately reads that recordset. Everything works fine, both read and write. However, when opening database and double clicking the field, I get the error mentioned earlier. If I make new record *manually* by adding the file into field, I can open it by double clicking. If I try to read it via code I get "junk characters" like I mentioned in my previous comment...

Comment: In my opinion, you have solved my problem, the file is written into DB and can be read. If you could explain to me what is going on, it would be a bonus ( I have read somewhere that *Package* means that OLE wraps the file, so that "junk" might be some sort of a header. Upvoted and officially accepted. Best regards.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff As you have discovered, the document files that you inserted through the Access user interface had an OLE "wrapper" applied to them, converting them from raw streams of bytes into "OLE Objects". That is the older way of dealing with such objects in Access. The only advantage is that you can open those documents *in Access* by double-clicking on them. The main disadvantage is that it makes it very difficult to use those documents in any other context (e.g., from a C++ app). Many developers are abandoning the "OLE wrapped" method and just storing the raw binary data.