# Display BLOB file in DocumentViewer

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, blob

I have a column of type BLOB in my MySQL database which stores various files. I am trying to select a file based on the fileNo specified by the user in a comboBox and display the file in the documentViewer (component by Xtreme DocumentStudio package). Here is the code that I have already:

```
string connection = "server=127.0.0.1; database=business;user=root; password=root01;";
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connection);

connect.Open();

MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand();

myCmd.Connection = connect;

myCmd.CommandText = "SELECT fileSubmitted FROM files WHERE fileNo = @fileNo;";

DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)comboBox4.SelectedItem;
int fileNo = Convert.ToInt32(drv[comboBox4.DisplayMember].ToString());
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileNo", fileNo);

byte[] bits = new byte[0];
bits = (byte[])myCmd.ExecuteScalar();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bits);
documentViewer1.LoadDocument(ms);
```

When I run the code I receive the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: `Buffer cannot be null.`
```

on the line: `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bits);`

I have been trying my best to solve this issue but not had any luck. I am not sure what I have already is remotely close to the solution or whether I am not indeed far off. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: First off, you don't need to bother with a DataAdapter or a DataTable if all you are interested in is `Row[0][0]`. You should be able to just use something like `bits = (byte[])myCmd.ExecuteScalar();`. Also, when asking for help with code be sure to include the *actual* results (behaviour, error messages, ...). "I have ... not had any luck." is not particularly informative.

Comment: Sorry for the maybe vague question Gord. I have adapted my code to include the statement you mentioned and removed the DataAdapter and DataTable and I get the following error:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Buffer cannot be null.

I have edited my code above too

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the error message you are receiving (from your comment above)  and also tell us which line of code is throwing the exception.

Comment: Ok I have now edited the question

Comment: Did you **verify** that your **select statement will return data**? It seems to me that your query does not return any data - thats why `bits` **is null** and therefore the constructor of MemoryStream fails!

Comment: thanks Pilgerstorfer you were right! my query was indeed not returning any data! works like a treat now!

Comment: thank you Gord for your help too

Comment: Glad to hear that it is working. Please take a moment to post your working code as an Answer so it may help others in the future.

Comment: I will do tomorrow as I'm currently away from my PC with the solution on it. I was just wondering if you could take a look at another question I posted. I'm not very good with these files stuff! haha my question can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647435/save-created-pdf-to-mysql-database-c-sharp