# Save created PDF to MySQL database C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, pdf, save

I want to be able to store newly created PDF in a BLOB  field in my MySQL database. This is the code I have so far but it saves to local disk instead:

```
        string fileName = employeeNo.ToString();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] bits = new byte[0];

        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
        doc.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rec2 = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
        doc.Add(new Paragraph(textBox2.Text));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph(textBox1.Text));
        doc.Close();
        bits.ToArray();
```

How could I adapt this so that it can be inserted into my database instead? The file would then be passed into the insert statement as below:

```
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feedbackComments", bits);
```

Comment: You don't want to convert the byte array to a string. You want to pass the byte array itself as the value of the parameter. Also, `bits.ToString()` doesn't do what you apparently think it does; it simply returns the string "System.Byte[]".

Comment: ok that makes sense. I've removed the .ToString() and nothing inserts to the database now. Before it inserted System.Byte[] as you said which wasn't exactly useful. Do you know what could be wrong with it?

Comment: It looks like `bits` is never updated, and `bits.ToArray();` is redundant.. Did you mean to do `bits = ms.ToArray();` ...?

Comment: You are not saving ms to bits. Bits should be initialized to a size required by ms prior to that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `FileStream` use a `MemoryStream` and extract the byte array with `ToArray()` after closing the doc.

Use the byte array to populate the table.

Comment: ok I have edited the code above. I'm not sure what else I need to change to it. Also, how can I name the file that will be saved to the database?

Comment: The code inserts the data into the database but when I try to open it from the database, Adobe Reader says that the file is either not supported or corrupted/damaged

Comment: As Gord Thompson said you need `myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feedbackComments", ms.ToArray())`;

Comment: Thank you and Gord for the advice, it worked! but how can I specify the file name when the file gets inserted into the database?

Comment: You'll need another column for the file name.

Comment: what column do you mean?

Comment: I can't seem to find a solution for it online :/

Comment: A column that you already have or that you have to create in the table (column=field).

Comment: is there anyway I can specify the filename before it gets stored in the database?

Comment: What you are storing is a blob of data, not a file.  Store the data, store the name.  When you want it back, you must reconstitute that blob into a new file using the name you stored.

Comment: ah yeah your right. So in my database I will have a column for the BLOB and another for the corresponding filename? how will I be able to show the filename on the pdf when retrieving it?

Comment: On my form I will have a view PDF button that will open the file using Adobe Acrobat. How will I be able to specify the filename that the user will see?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any solution online that would do this. Have you guys got any idea?